# How do you salvage gear in V Rising?

Tags: v-rising

I have some gear that I don't need anymore. If I look at the description, it says, "Salvaegable", but I haven't figured out what I need to do. Does anyone know how to salvage it?

[image]

Comment: You will be able to salvage more than just gear as well

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [this guide](https://gamerant.com/v-rising-how-to-salvage-weapons-items/), you need to build a "Devourer", which it looks like you first need to unlock the blueprint for.

> Players that would like to salvage their unneeded items will need to have access to the Devourer, a special chest that is constructed from 12 Planks and six Copper Ingots. Survival game fans will not be able to build this container immediately upon starting the game, though, as they must first unlock its blueprint. To do this, players will need to dispatch Lidia the Chaos Archer, a Level 26 boss that can be tracked through the Blood Altar.

[Other posts](https://www.gosunoob.com/guides/v-rising-salvage-weapons-items/) say you pretty much get this by following the questline.

> To get this chest, follow the starting questline as you normally would. Soon, you will get the “Expanding my Domain” quest. As part of this quest, one of the steps requires you to “Upgrade the Castle Heart and interact with it”. Go to your Castle’s Blood Altar and select it. Doing so will bring up a separate menu with bosses that you can track and fight. Defeating them will get you access to some advanced buildings, such as the Tannery.

> The boss you are looking for here is called Lidia the Chaos Archer. Select her and choose the “Track Blood” option, which will lead you to her. Once you have defeated her, you will get the blueprint for the Devourer Chest. To build it, you will need the following materials: x12 Planks and x6 Copper Bars. Once you have created it, you can then use it to salvage the weapons and items that you no longer want to get back the components that were used to make them.

Comment: Can also confirm this from personal experience :)